# browserstate/ajaxify: Problems while loading jquery dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, history.js

**Intro**

I'm using [browserstate/ajaxify](https://github.com/browserstate/ajaxify) to turn my (wordpress)portfolio into a website that only reloads parts of the site if necessary(ajaxify) with the certainty that every change is visible in the address bar and above all SEO optimized(history api).

My portfolio consists of two templates. Overview page with 9 project/links to detailpage. And a detail page with a Titel, text,video & images.

**Problem**

I'm using [fitvid](http://fitvidsjs.com/) library on the detailpage to add responsiveness to the vimeo player. This piece of javascript doesn't work while the detailpage is loaded asynchronous(using browserstate/ajaxify). So jquery, fitvid and my main.js  needs to be added again dynamically.

I've tried to use getScript in document.ready to load these files dynamically unfortunately without any success.

```
$.getScript("http://portfolio/wp-content/themes/rwd_theme/javascripts/foundation/jquery.js")
.done(function(script, textStatus) {
    console.log( textStatus );
});

$.getScript("http://portfolio/wp-content/themes/rwd_theme/js/jquery.fitvid.js")
.done(function(script, textStatus) {
    console.log( textStatus );
});
$.getScript("http://portfolio/wp-content/themes/rwd_theme/js/main.js")
.done(function(script, textStatus) {
    console.log( textStatus );
});
```

Comment: since `$.getScript` is a jQuery method, you can't use it until after jQuery is loaded. using it to load jQuery doesn't make sense.